# Sub domain mapping to a page

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm creating an HTML page (GWT Module) for mobile browsers, It's currently on "www.mydomain.com/Mobile.html".

How can I map this sub domain "m.mydomain.com" on App-Engine to view this page and keep the address bar showing "m.mydomain.com"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to do this properly from GAE, So As a workaround I created a "URL Frame" also known as "Frame Redirect" or "URL masking" from my domain registrar to mask my html page with the sub-domain wanted.

So far, I don't see any problems with this.

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest to have responsive site instead of creating separate subdomain for mobile.

if you insist follow the link, it might help you
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/domain#more_about_wildcard_subdomain_mapping

alternatively you could write js code to redirect user based on resolution of device

```
<script type=”text/javascript”>
if (screen.width <= 699) {
  document.location = "http://example.com/Mobile.html"
}
</script>
```

Comment: The link does not show how to map a sub domain to any page. It only has mapping to diffrent versions and app engine modules